# Need to fetch all users that logged in user is following as an objects

Tags: php, sql, database, model-view-controller

I am building handmade MVC framework, and I want to implement following system (Like Twitter) so User that is signed in can follow another user and when that signed in user visits his profile he can see all other users that he is following and vice versa.  I am not sure which query to apply in order to fetch all the users that current logged in user is following. I tried couple of sql queries in order to fetch those followers as an objects but failed. Further you have tables users and follows and their explanation.

This is users table.

[image]

This is follows table which has composite primary key (user_id,following_user_id) and they are both foreign keys that are pointing to column id from table users

[image]

Here is some data from follows table

[image]

I've tried this but it is fetching every user (as an array)

`SELECT users.id,users.username FROM follows INNER JOIN users ON follows.user_id = users.id;`

Comment: Either just convert the array to your own custom object (recommended) or [`fetch_object()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php) to have it get you a `stdClass` (or specify a class as the first parameter). MySQL isn't aware of objects, that is up to your code.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I am aware of that, but I am not sure which query to apply in order to fetch all the users that current logged in user is following.

Comment: Nothing in the schema that you provided shows anything about "being logged in". If you haven't done so already, you'll need to build that. Your code will need to "ping" the server/database every `x` units of times (seconds, minutes, etc.) for each user to say "I'm still here" unless you want to trust that every user will actually log out, which they won't. One way is to have an extra column "user last seen" and have the pinger update that. Then your query can say "give me all users that have been seen in the past 5 minutes" or something similar.

Comment: follow is like friends except for accepted/rejected/pending status, so should perhaps have arbitrary profile_a and profile_b column, then you can do a SELECT CASE WHEN profile_a = ? THEN profile_b ELSE profile_a END AS profile_id WHERE (profile_a = ? OR profile_b = ?), and pass in the logged in id because at some point your also want to also query what a current profile you're looking at is following which is not you or someone your following

Comment: @ChrisHaas I already have everything worked out. That is not the problem, problem is that I want to show all users that a for example user with id=1 is logged in and he follows a user with id=4 now when I visit a profile of logged in user (one with id=1) I want to display a table which contains all the users that he is following (it should display username of user with id=4

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thank you this worked !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `user`
(
    `user_id` int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varChar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
);

CREATE table `user_following`
(
    `user_id` int,
    `following_user_id` int,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `following_user_id`),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`following_user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`)
);
```

With these values:

```sql
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (1, 'Alice');
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (2, 'Bob');
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (3, 'Charlie');

INSERT INTO `user_following` VALUES (1, 2);
```

You can find all of the users that "Alice" (user id=1) follows by running:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `user`
WHERE
    `user_id`
    IN
    (SELECT `following_user_id` FROM `user_following` WHERE `user_id` = 1);
```